# Creating a directory and folder in the internal storage using android studio

Tags: java, android

I have read online that to make a directory in the internal storage we use the following line of code

```
File dir = getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

however, when I execute this code along with my entire source code, I can't seem to find the directory I created in my phone. Isn't it supposed to be saved into the android/data directory where all other apps data is stored? I am slightly confused.

Comment: What code in function getDir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

private file stored in

```
/data/data/<packagename>/files
```

Comment: if it's not private it would go to the place I had originally thought right?